# Some problems about isomorphism of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> 1) Let $G=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb {Z}_4\times\mathbb {Z}_2)$. Show that $|G|\leq8$ and then $G \cong D_4$.
>
> 2) Show that $\mathrm{Aut}(S_3\times \mathbb {Z}_3) \cong S_3\times\mathbb {Z}_2$.

At the moment I was able to do the first part of the first problem. I noticed that $\mathbb {Z}_4\times\mathbb {Z}_2$ has two generators, $(1,0),(0,1)$, so an automorphism $ϕ$ will be fixed if I choose their images. Both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ have order $4$, and I can see that there are only $4$ elements of order $4$, so I only have $4$ elements that can be their images. Because of this facts I have $4$ possibilities for $ϕ((1,0))$, but only $2$ for $ϕ((0,1))$, because it can't be an element of order $4$ that is in the subgroup generated by $ϕ((1,0))$. So $|G|=8$. Is it correct?

Comment: You've shown that the automorphism group has *at most* 8 elements, not that it's order 8.

Comment: Sure, you're right, but in reality the first part of the problem was to show that G has at most 8 elements

Answer (score 0):

Hint: To see that $G\simeq D_4$, observe that there are four elements of $(\mathbb{Z}/4)\times(\mathbb{Z}/2)$ which are of order $4$.  Namely, these elements are $\{(1,0),(3,0),(1,1),(3,1)\}$.  Observe that these form two pairs of inverses ($(1,0)+(3,0)=(0,0)$ and $(1,1)+(3,1)=(0,0)$).  These four points can be represented as a square 
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
(1,0)&\cdots&(1,1)\\
\vdots&&\vdots\\
(3,1)&\cdots&(3,0)
\end{array}
$$
Observe that inverses are shown as opposite corners of the square.  $G$ acts by symmetry on that square (requires proof).

Comment: Sorry, I am not of sure I have understood what you said.. what do you mean when you say "acts by symmetry"?

Comment: @GRE $D_4$ is the symmetry group of the square.  The four elements above form a square.  The automorphism group acts as the symmetry group on those four elements.